# I want to add list of items with two text in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to add a list of items with two text also, please help me with this, my database class is:

DBHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "NewDBtest";
    private final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private final static String TABLE_NAME = "table1";
    private final static String COL_ID = "id";

    private final static String COL_imei = "imei";
    private final static String COL_contact = "contactNo";
    private static final String KEY_ListItem = "listitem";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        //1. Initialised database
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //2. Create table
        String createTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COL_imei + " TEXT," +
                COL_contact + " TEXT," +

                KEY_ListItem + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTableQuery);

    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
//
        onCreate(db);

    }

    void addListItem(ArrayList<String> listItem) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

//        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        for (int i = 0; i < listItem.size(); i++) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            Log.e("vlaue inserting==", "" + listItem.get(i));
            values.put(KEY_ListItem, listItem.get(i));
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        }
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }



    Cursor getListItem() {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        return cursor;
    }



    // ### OWN CRUD METHODS ###
    // Create / Insert


    public long insert(User user) {
        // 1. init database object
        SQLiteDatabase DataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. init ContentValues object
        ContentValues row = new ContentValues();

        row.put(COL_imei, user.getImeiNo());
        row.put(COL_contact, user.getContact_1());

        //3. insert row into table
        long id = DataBase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, row);
        //4. disconnect database
        DataBase.close();
        if (id != 0) {
            return id;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public List<User> readAll() {
        //1.Init database
        SQLiteDatabase DataBase = this.getReadableDatabase();

        //2.create query
        String selectAllQuery = "Select * from " + TABLE_NAME;

        //3. fire query and catch output into cursor object
        Cursor result = DataBase.rawQuery(selectAllQuery, null);

        // 4. Iterate through a result
        if (result != null) {
            //4.1 move pointer to first row
            boolean isFirstRow = result.moveToFirst();
            //4.2 create list of users object
            List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();

            //result.moveToFirst();
            if (isFirstRow) {
                do {
                    String idOfName = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_ID));

                    String name = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_imei));
                    String last_name = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_contact));

                    User object = new User();

                    object.setId1(idOfName);

                    object.setImeiNo(name);
                    object.setContact_1(last_name);

                    list.add(object);
                }
                while (result.moveToNext());
                return list;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, add list item is the list wich i want to store in "insert" function means when i call insert from another class it will store the text as well as list,

Comment: Please elaborate your question more. what is your database schema?

Answer (score 0):

you can not add list directly. you can call this method addListItem() in loop.

Answer (score -2):

You can not insert list in column directly but you can do it using JSON,

Consider below code for reference purpose and you can do it for your requirement,

**First Convert Your List in JSON And then in String As Below**

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("listObject", new JSONArray(listItem.get(i)));
// If you have one object then use JSONObject instead of JSONArray
String arrayList = json.toString();
values.put(KEY_ListItem, arrayList);
```

By this way you can insert data

**To get data from Database use below code**

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(KEY_ListItem);
ArrayList items = json.optJSONArray("listObject");
```

This will help you for your requirement.